# Getting error while Requesting for token and claims from on premises ADFS via Proxy

Tags: iis, proxy, adfs, arr

First I am new to the topic ADFS and Reverse proxy. The goal is a Single-Sign-On OAuth2 authentication for SPA Web application.

I have an on premises ADFS Server called "Server-A" which is on "Domain-A" and an web server called "Server-B" which is on "Domain-B". Also I have one proxy server called "Server-C". Now if any user want to access any resource of my web Server-B then they need to authenticate first and this happening via ADFS(Server-A), this ADFS call is happening via proxy Server-C.

Problem –

If I am trying to access ADFS server directly (without proxy) then user able to login and I am getting token and claims both. But if I am trying to access via proxy then when posting back the token throwing below error(found on ADFS event log) –

```
Encountered error during federation passive request. 

Additional Data 

Protocol Name: 
wsfed 

Relying Party: 


Exception details: 
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: encodedGenericRequest
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.GenericProtocolRequest..ctor(String encodedGenericRequest)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.WSFederation.WSFederationProtocolHandler.GetOriginalRequestFromResponse(ProtocolContext context)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.PassiveProtocolListener.ProcessProtocolRequest(ProtocolContext protocolContext, PassiveProtocolHandler protocolHandler)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.PassiveProtocolListener.OnGetContext(WrappedHttpListenerContext context)
```

> I am using ADFS 3.0 and Window Server 2012 R2 and reverse proxy using
>   ARR and URL rewrite module on IIS.

I am looking for a solution for the above issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem? Please explain if you did... I am running into this issue as well.